# How to check if more than one space or beginning has space in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

1. `Hello     World`
2. `Hello     World`
3. `hello world`     
   or if the very beginning has space
4. `Hello World`

It works if `$q` has normal values but I am getting `$q` value from **search input** and so it does not work except case 1.

```
$q = Input::get('q');

if(preg_match("/^\s+/", $q) || preg_match("/\s{2,}/", $q)) {
        echo 'Found Spaces';    
}
```

Comment: that match the first time with at least 2 spaces consecutive

Comment: Besides... Why two `preg_match`? Could just use one with `^\s|\s\s` or `(?:^|\s)\s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of  `Input::get('q');` use `$q = $_GET['q'];` 
So your code becomes:

```
   $q = $_GET['q'];
    
    if(preg_match("/^\s+/", $q) || preg_match("/\s{2,}/", $q)) {
            echo 'Found Spaces';    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(preg_match("/^\s+/", $q) || preg_match("/\s{2,}/", $q))
    {
       
    }
```

Comment: i have edited the code ...this will work fine

Comment: it is because of `$q = Input::get('q');`

Answer (score 1):

```
/\s+/g
```

- `\s` to match space.
- `+` to said at least one.
- `g` globally tag, all matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single call to preg_match with an alternation `|` to check for both scenario's.

As `\s` can also [match a newline](https://regex101.com/r/090WuY/1), you can use `\h` to match a horizontal whitespace char.

```
^\h|\h\h
```

Regex demo

```
$q = Input::get('q');

if(preg_match("/^\h|\h\h/", $q) ) {
    echo 'Found Spaces';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using PHP `trim()` function? Use trim() to remove redundant whitespaces, then apply more advanced filter or whatever you name it.
In case you want a boolean value, just check if the original string is different from trimmed string.
Document: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php